# Avoid hardware limitation while competing in Kaggle?

Tags: scikit-learn, kaggle

I've learned machine learning via textbooks and examples, which don't delve into the engineering challenges of working with "big-ish" data like Kaggle's.

As a specific example, I'm working on the [New York taxi trip challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/nyc-taxi-trip-duration). It's a regression task for ~ 2 million rows and 20 columns.

My 4GB-RAM laptop can barely do EDA with `pandas` and `matplotlib` in Jupyter Notebook. However, when I try to build a random forest with 1000 trees, it hangs (e.g. Kernel restart error in Jupyter Notebook).

To combat this, I set up a 16GB-RAM desktop. I then ssh in, start a browser-less Jupyter Notebook kernel, and [connect my local Notebook to that kernel](http://amber-md.github.io/pytraj/latest/tutorials/remote_jupyter_notebook). However, I still max out that machine.

At this point, I'm guessing that I need to run my model training code as a script.

- Will this help with my machine hanging?
- What's the workflow to store the model results and use it later for prediction? Do you use a Makefile to keep this reproducible?
- Doing this also sacrifices the interactivity of Jupyter Notebook -- is there a workflow that maintains the interactivity?

My current toolkit is RStudio, Jupyter Notebook, Emacs, but am willing to pick up new things.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes - a Python script will have less overhead than a Jupyter Notebook
- Pickle is the standard way to store a scikit-learn model, see [model persistence documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).
- The two primary ways to scale Jupyter Notebooks is vertical (rent a bigger machine on a cloud service provider) or horizontal (spin-up a cluster).